# Apex Triggers and Custom Objects

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object named Trip. I am trying to create an apex trigger that will execute after any trip is created, that will create an event with some of the info from the trip. I am new to apex code so please bear with me. The problem i'm encountering often is that i want to assign the account that was assigned to the trip, to the event. My code is:

```
trigger CreateEvent on Trip__c(after insert){
   List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
   for(Trip__c tripObj : Trigger.new){
      Event event = new Event();
      //event.Account  = tripObj.Account__c;  *problem is here*
      event.Subject = tripObj.Name;
      event.OwnerId = tripObj.CreatedById;
      eventList.add(event);
   }
   if(eventList.size()>0){
      upsert eventList;
   }
}
```

How can I get the account object that was assigned to the trip, to assign it to the event? In my code I know that I'm not assigning the account object, I am assigning a lookup field. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Is it not AccountId rather than just Account?

Comment: Nope, as Sai correctly pointed out, its WhatId. In the following link you can find all the object references: http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf

Comment: Good to know, glad you got your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
event.Account  = tripObj.Account__c;
```

with

```
event.whatid  = tripObj.Account__c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Salesforce/Apex development!

If you check out the [Salesforce.com documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm), you'll see that the field you're looking for on the `Event` object is called `WhatId`:

> **WhatId**: ID of a related Account, Opportunity, Campaign, Case, or custom object. Label is **Opportunity/Account ID**.

As such, you can replace `event.Account` with `event.WhatId` and you should be all set.  In general, it's a good step to double-check the name of the field you're trying to use, which you can do in the documentation I linked to, or directly in the Salesforce.com setup pages.